# Building Dynamic Classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ruby, dynamic, objective-c-runtime

I'm a somewhat competent ruby programmer. Yesterday I decided to finally try my hand with Apple's Cocoa frameworks. Help me see things the ObjC way?

I'm trying to get my head around `objc_allocateClassPair` and `objc_registerClassPair`. My goal is to dynamically generate a few classes and then be able to use them as I would any other class. Does this work in Obj C?

Having allocated and registered class `A`, I get a compile error when calling `[[A alloc] init];` (it says `'A' Undeclared`). I can only instantiate `A` using runtime's `objc_getClass` method. Is there any way to tell the compiler about `A` and pass it messages like I would `NSString`? A compiler flag or something?

I have 10 or so other classes (`B`, `C`, …), all with the same superclass. I want to message them directly in code  (`[A classMethod]`, `[B classMethod]`, …) without needing `objc_getClass`. Am I trying to be too dynamic here or just botching my implementation? It looks something like this…

```
 NSString *name = @"test";  
 Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair([NSString class], [name UTF8String], 0);  
 objc_registerClassPair(newClass);  

 id a = [[objc_getClass("A") alloc] init];  
 NSLog(@"new class: %@ superclass: %@", a, [a superclass]);  
 //[[A alloc] init]; blows up.
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you elaborated on what you are actually trying to achieve. In *most* applications, using plumbing functions like `objc_registerClassPair` and `objc_getClass` could be considered a *really* bad sign that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: This is a fairly atypical coding pattern.   Generally, dynamic class generation is pretty limited in Objective-C applications.  Most developers focus more on creating an object model flexible enough to contain whatever is needed.  (Not saying dynamic class generation is always the wrong answer -- certainly it is a good bit of fun to pursue).

Comment: Thanks to you both. I was hoping to use generate the classes within a loop to to save myself typing them each out longhand (DRY!), but I'll find another way.

Comment: Again, exactly what are you trying to achieve? Are the classes all just aliases for one class?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that `[[A alloc] init];` blows up is that the compiler has no clue what `A` means. The compiler never knows that `A` is even there.

**Edit:** Also, it looks like what you want is:

```
@interface A : NSObject {
  NSString *myString;
}

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string;

- (void)doItToIt;

@end
```

or perhaps

```
@interface NSString (MyPrivateExtension)

- (void)doItToIt;

@end
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems like going it the normal way works better. In ruby generated classes behave the same way as conventionally declared classes and I was hoping that I might be able to get the same effect here.

Comment: @kjell_: you do realize that these are two *wildly* different languages, yes?

Comment: Oh, absolutely. But that doesn't stop me from wanting to keep repetitive boilerplate code to a minimum.

Comment: This answer is invalid. It is possible to create classes dynamically at runtime in Objective-C. 'objc_allocateClassPair' and 'objc_registerClassPair' accomplish the goal of the question. More reading here: [Mike Ash: Creating Classes at Runtime in Objective-C](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: @TaylorHalliday: The compiler still won't know about these classes at runtime, which is the problem that has to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class in the Objective-C language, the compiler defines a new type. When you create a class dynamically, the compiler has no knowledge of that type, so your only choice is to use the class as an id, and send messages to it dynamically. Ruby is a dynamically typed language that likely uses the same mechanisms as the compiler when defining classes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html and https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime

It describes just what you're trying to achieve and provides a nice abstraction over raw Objective-C runtime calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the fabulous [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/) and [FSClass](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~weinrich/projects/FSClass/index.html) which can do this and are open source. FSClass defines a meta-class that can be subclassed at runtime.

It does work by using **objc_allocateClassPair** and **objc_registerClassPair** but there is alot of other stuff going on (beyond me!) that would probably help.